# UK visa return shipping label question

Tags: visas, uk, return

Section 3 of the visa application instructions says the following:
3.1 Return shipping
To have your documents returned you must provide a fully addressed prepaid electronic shipping label (we cannot accept ground services and non-electronic waybills). Put your return shipping label and envelope inside the package, and keep a copy of the waybill for your records.

What does non-electronic waybills mean?

Answer (score 4):

With FedEx it is possible to use waybills (shipping labels) that are written by hand, rather than printed with barcodes, text, etc. The consulate is saying that they do not accept these handwritten documents.

Here is an example of the FedEx handwritten waybill. The consulate does not accept this style of shipping document:

[image: FedEx handwritten waybill]

The online FedEx waybill will look something like this (though it may also be printed vertically). This shipping document is OK:

[image: FedEx online waybill]